# Дозаписать значение в поле таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно дозаписать значение в поле таблицы mysql php.
Данная команда перезаписывает значение:

```
$s1="UPDATE users SET sotrudnik='".$_POST['user_id']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
```

А как дописать значение?

Comment: Никак. Хранение нескольких значений в одном поле нарушает первую нормальную форму и приводит в реляционных БД к массе проблем, как с записью так и с поиском. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @Mike жесть....

Comment: Ну записать вы конечно можете (см. функцию concat()), но поверьте, после этого для работы с этим полем вам придется написать десятки если не сотни строк кода. Отдельная таблица для хранения таких значений значительно упрощает жизнь. И по тому какой запрос вы написали могу заключить что вы не следуете даваемым вам примерам. Вы подставляете значение переменных непосредственно в запрос, что ведет к замедлению работы и главное к sql-инъекциям. более 50% взломов всех сайтов в мире обязаны именно подстановкам переменных в текст. _Никогда_ так не делайте.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$s1="UPDATE users SET sotrudnik=CONCAT (sotrudnik, '; ', '".$_POST['user_id']."') WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
```

Вот пример дописывания данных через `;`, хотя хранение данных таким образом противоречит идеологии реляционных баз данных.